# Change TinyMCE input height from textarea height

Tags: input, tinymce, textarea, height

My form uses inputs and textareas, some of which I've added as TinyMCE elements. The problem is that the inputs are converted into the same size as the textareas. I'd like the inputs to be the same height as non-TinyMCE input fields (I'm using the latest version of TinyMCE - 3.5b2).

For example, TinyMCE adds this table to the inputs and textareas:

`<table role="presentation" id="teaser_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 590px; height: 100px; ">`

How can I change this embedded style to reduce the height for inputs to 30px?

*I've also [posted this](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=99936#p99936) on the TinyMCE forums.*

Answer (score 3):

```
<table role="presentation" id="teaser_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 590px; height: 100px; ">
```

That is exactly the element you will need to change. Tinymce has the width and height init param, but there are some cases where this setting is not sufficient.
Due to the fact that the editor iframe explicitly gets the same height assigned you will have to adjust the iframe too. You will need to call

```
var new_val = '30px';

// adjust table element
$('#' + 'my_editorid' + '_tbl').css('height', new_val);

//adjust iframe
$('#' + 'my_editorid' + '_ifr').css('height', new_val);
```

Idealy, this should be done right on editor initialization. So use:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {

        var new_val = '30px';

        // adjust table element
        $('#' + ed.id + '_tbl').css('height', new_val);

        //adjust iframe
        $('#' + ed.id + '_ifr').css('height', new_val);
      });
   }
});
```

**Update:** Solution without jQuery:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {

          var new_val = '30px';

          // adjust table element
          var elem = document.getElementById(ed.id + '_tbl');
          elem.style.height = new_val;

          // adjust iframe element
          var iframe = document.getElementById(ed.id + '_ifr');
          iframe.style.height = new_val;
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to get this working (both fields are still the same height). I used the example pages from a fresh TinyMCE download: http://bit.ly/GS6FBK

Comment: hmmm, work perfectly with my page - oops found an error and changed the code - check it out now (had onClick instead of onInit)

Comment: I used the updated code and now the textarea doesn't have TinyMCE, nor is the input 30px tall. Am I doing something wrong? http://bit.ly/GS6FBK

Comment: do you get any error? (do you use an error console (i.e. firebug))

Comment: No errors that I can see. You can view the page here: http://bit.ly/GS6FBK. Do you have a demo URL of this working?

Comment: yes, here is the working example using a tinymce fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/flbaab

Comment: i got two errors using your demo page - looks like jQuery is not defined - i will adjust my answer so you won't have to use jQuery